# Can't get div to hide by id not class

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to simply hide something when the page loads...I'm actually going to have quite a few things hidden eventually, but right now I can get this to hide.  I've scrolled some of the answers I've found on SO, but can't get it working.  I have to keep the .jumbotron class for css so I simply added an id onto it...........not sure if that's the problem or what....here's my code.  I left out the beginning as nobody really needs to see that.

```
  <!-- Jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Data Loader</h1>
        <p class="lead">Follow the directions to load your data.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Start</a>
      </div>

      <div id="second_slide" class="jumbotron" >
        <h1>Data Loader</h1>
        <p class="lead">Follow the directions to load your data.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Start</a>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">

        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script>
      //doesn't work
     $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.jumbotron #second_slide').click(function(){
      var index=$('.jumbotron #second_slide').index(this);
      $('.jumbotron #second_slide').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: You call `$('.jumbotron #second_slide').hide();` inside the click event of the same object. You should use `var $this = $(this);` and `$this.hide();`. Also, the `index` variable is private and used no-where else. You can get rid of that.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because there is no element with an ID of 'second_slide' inside an element with a class of 'jumbotron'.

Try this:

```
$('.jumbotron#second_slide').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Data Loader</h1>
    <p class="lead">Follow the directions to load your data.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Start</a>


  <div id="second_slide" class="jumbotron" >
    <h1>Data Loader</h1>
    <p class="lead">Follow the directions to load your data.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Start</a>
  </div></div>
```

Comment: I already gave that putting the id first a shot....I can do it in CSS and then when I want it to change I can just change it with javascript and document.getElementById(#second_slide).html = ....... so on and so forth but I thought jquery would make this easy....Do I need jquery UI?  crap I didn't even think about that.

Comment: `document.getElementById(#second_slide).html ` will not work `document.getElementById(#second_slide).innerHtml ` this will work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('#second_slide').click(function(){
      var index=$('#second_slide').index(this);
      $(this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is  the selector in `$('.jumbotron #second_slide')`. All you need is the id: `$('#second_slide')`.

`$('.jumbotron #second_slide')` is trying to find an element with `id="second_slide"` within the `class="jumbotron"` divs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ? Writing something like .clazz #id you actually want to search for the id inside .clazz. You should probably iterate through those jumbotrons and select one you're interested in, then extract that component.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a go:

```
$(function(){
    $('#second_slide').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

That's the entire `<script>` element.